# Why is bokeh plot on web server loading so slow?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, bokeh

I really like bokeh and I'd like to have a bokeh plot on my website. Running bokeh locally (on Linux) with `bokeh serve` works like a charm. But I am having a really hard time getting it to run smoothly on the web server.

I am running it on a DigitalOcean droplet (ubuntu 18.04 with LAMP stack and reverse-proxy nginx). Since I read that `bokeh serve` is not meant for production, I tried to set up a more secure and robust environment. I used this [article](https://rbtechblog.com/blog/deploy_bokeh_app) to get started. With another [DigitalOcean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) and lots of online research and trial&error, I finally got it to work.

Well, at least kind of, because it is incredibly slow. To a point that it took me a while noticing it worked in the first place and it is pretty much unusable. It takes usually 4s, sometimes up to 10s (given my internet connection is not very fast).

The html from the template loads pretty fast though. But
`bokeh.min.js?v=540...` (748KB)
`bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=409...` (97KB)
`bokeh-tables.min.js?v=623...` (256KB)
`bokeh-gl.min.js?v=823...` (62KB)
take very long.

I checked, and this is also the case for the website with the [article](https://rbtechblog.com/blog/deploy_bokeh_app) I used as starting point.
The official bokeh examples (e.g. [weather](https://demo.bokeh.org/weather)) load pretty quick with graphs that are far more complex, but there the aforementioned files are also way smaller.

This is part of the nginx conf file:

```
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/user/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

    # reverse proxy to embedded bokeh apps
    location /bokeh/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5100;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
```

This is the plot file `run_bokeh.py`:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.server.server import Server

def run(doc):

    x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

    fig = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')
    fig.line(x, y, legend="Temp.", line_width=2)

    layout = column(fig)
    doc.add_root(layout)


kws = {'port': 5100, 'prefix': '/bokeh', 'allow_websocket_origin': ['my-domain.com']}
server = Server(run, **kws)
server.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, '/')
    server.io_loop.start()
```

and the flask file `myproject.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import server_document

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    tag = server_document(url=r'/bokeh', relative_urls=True)
    return render_template('index.html', tag=tag)
```

**I couldn't figure out how to make the `bokeh.....min.js` files smaller, nor if there is something fundamentally wrong with my setup.**

#### PS:

I could find plenty of tutorials (even video tutorials) on how to use bokeh in dev mode, with `bokeh serve`. But very little on how to use it in production. So if someone can point me in a direction, on how to properly learn using bokeh on a production server, I would appreciate that greatly.

### Update

- I think I didn't articulate properly what I meant. By *making the `bokeh.....min.js` files smaller*, I meant that the file that is loaded in my setup is four times as large as the one in the official example or the CDN
  `https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=547e7d2591695b654def5914bdd697fa` → 748 KB
  `https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js` → 202 KB
  And I was wondering how to get to the 202 KB
- I tried to us the CDN but it doesn't work.
  I added `from bokeh.resources import CDN` to `myproject.py` but then I couldn't figure out where to insert `CDN` (`server_document(...)` is expecting a string for recources)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.resources import CDN

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")

def index():
    # tag = server_document(url=r'/bokeh', relative_urls=True, CDN)
    tag = server_document(url=r'/bokeh', relative_urls=True, CDN)
    return render_template('index.html', tag=tag)
```

When I manually add the scripts to the template file `index.html`, it gets blocked(*blocked-mixed-content*) and the other scripts are loaded anyways.

```
<link href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-1.3.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Have you tried running any [performance analysis tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference)? It might help highlight the problem area.

Comment: The docstring for `server_document` states that `resources` can either be `'default'` or `None`. If you want to put the resource URLs in the template yourself, you would pass `None` to tell Bokeh that you are handling things manually.

Comment: Thank you! That worked, it now loads in a reasonable time.

Comment: Is this a good way to do it (`resources=None` and  manually adding them in template file)? Or is there a other recommended way? I try to avoid picking up bad practices

Comment: It's not how I would do it, but it's fine. I would set the environment variable `BOKEH_RESOURES=cdn` when running the bokeh server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I should mention is that the next version of Bokeh (1.4) will support:

- direct SSL termination (i.e. https connections)
- providing "auth hooks" for login/logout

That said, there will still be good reasons to run behind a proxy like Nginx sometimes, e.g. for load balancing.

On to your specific problem: One reason the demo site might load those resources faster is that it is configured to load them from the Bokeh CDN. In the [Dockerfile for the demo site](https://github.com/bokeh/demo.bokeh.org/blob/master/Dockerfile), it does:

```
ENV BOKEH_RESOURCES=cdn
```

So you could also try setting the `BOKEH_RESOURCES` environment variable before running your Bokeh server. Loading from CDN (which is AWS Cloudfront):

- is probably faster than loading from DO
- will take some off the load of the Bokeh server itself
- allows the JS files to be cached by users' browsers

So that's my first suggestion. If after that, things are still too slow, then we could look at removing unneeded JS files (e.g. if you are not using WebGL or `DataTables` then at least two of those files are not needed at all). But that might take some more back and forth discussion and experimentation, since I am not sure that's do-able without using the server "programmatically". So I'd say the [Bokeh Project Discourse](https://discourse.bokeh.org) is a better venue that discussion than SO.

As for:

> I couldn't figure out how to make the bokeh.....min.js files smaller

There is no way to make them smaller, they are the size they are. In a recent version the size did grow some due to inlining CSS but that is offset by not having to load separate CSS file any longer. The total load size should be roughly equivalent (we actually have CI tests that will fail if the size grows unexpectedly).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I still couldn't figure it out. I added a update to the question.

Comment: Thie file is 748kb unzipped. If you are seeing a smaller number from the CDN it is because Cloudfront can automatically gzip content before sending. If you want to do that locally, you would need to use a proxy like nginx configured to gzip static files, as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: And if you are running `bokeh serve` then to use CDN resources you need to set an *environment variable* in the shell (e.g. bash or powershell or whatever). You would also need to set environment vairables to use the proxy, too (to tell bokeh server to load resources from there, instead of itself)

Answer (score 1):

Nginx is excellent at serving static files. Use it to serve your's.

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/user/myproject/static/;
}
```

If you want to further make you `...min.js` files smaller, use `gzip`

```
location /static/ {
    alias /home/user/myproject/static/;
    gzip on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types
        text/javascript;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly an option (and in fact how the demo site used to be set up in the past) but FWIW the project CDN also already compresses the files, and using it does not require this additional configuration.

Comment: I assumed since he was trying to compress files, he was self hosting them. If a public CDN is an option for him, it's certainly the easiest way to solve his problem (if serving static files is indeed the source of his problem).

Comment: Thank you, would that mean that in my case I have to add `alias /home/user/myproject/bokeh/static/`(with `.../bokeh/...`)? Even though that folder doesn't really exist (e.g. when I check the *myproject* directory with `ls`). I am sorry for my incompetence, but this is very confusing to me.

Comment: This is all much more complicated than setting one environment variable `BOKEH_RESOURCES=cdn` when you run the bokeh server.

Comment: Is it correct that I would have to add `/bokeh` in front of `/static/`?

Comment: Without the `/bokeh` nothing changes, with I get 404 errors for the scripts. Or do I have to manually copy the files to that location?

Comment: @jost21 - The directory after `alias` definitely needs to exist on your server. You should use whatever directory your `...min.js` files are located in. Then your `...min.js` files can be accssed through `http://yoursite.com/static/bokeh.min.js`

Comment: There's lots of great [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/) on serving static files with nginx.

Comment: Ok, that was the part that was confusing me. Before the `...min.js` files were not uploaded by me but I guess generated by the bokeh service. In the browser the path was shown as `https://my-domain.com/bokeh/static/js/bokeh.min.js?v=547e7d2591695b654def5914bdd697fa`, hence I assumed that I have to use this path